# Is it possible to launch an atom at enough speed to compact other atoms?

Tags: forces, atomic-physics, collision

I’m just a 12 year old kid and don’t know much about physics but I was thinking could you hypothetically speed up an atom to a certain point then launch it at an object resulting in the atoms that make it up to be more condensed together. And if so would that make the object smaller? I might be totally wrong but just wanted to see.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but not permanently.

You can certainly compress a material (either by squeezing it or by firing a projectile into a target) so that the atoms rearrange themselves into a tighter geometry. We do this to study how minerals behave deep in the Earth for example. But as soon as the pressure is removed they will return to the state with the lowest energy for normal room temperature and pressure.

We can also make new materials by firing atomic nuclei fast enough that they get captured by an atom in the target and make a completely new element. This is how those new elements at the bottom right of the atomic table get made,one atom at a time in an accelerator. Although they only live for tiny fractions of a second before splitting up again.